# gt R Tables - Colour entire rows based on values in one column

Tags: r, gt

I'd like to colour an entire row based on the values in one column using the R package gt.
What I'd like is shown below, where rows are red for the smallest values of mpg, and blue for the highest values.

[image: table of mtcars with rows coloured by the values in the mpg column]

Using the code below:

```
mtcars |> 
  head() |> 
  select(mpg, cyl, disp, drat) |> 
  gt() |> 
  data_color(
    columns = mpg,
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue"),
    domain = c(18, 23))
  )
```

Gives the right behaviour only for the mpg column itself.

[image: gt table with only one column coloured]

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to create breaks, then use that for the rows argument in `tab_style` rather than using `data_color` (which doesn't have a rows argument). Here, I set the breaks using `cut`, but you could use something like `ntile` to break up into groups (commented out below).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

mtcars |>
  head() |>
  select(mpg, cyl, disp, drat) |>
  #mutate(breaks = ntile(mpg, 4)) |>
  mutate(breaks = cut(mpg, breaks = c(0, 18.2, 18.8, 21.5, 30), right = T, labels = F)) |>
  gt() |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "red"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = breaks == 1)
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "orange"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = breaks == 2)
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "green"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = breaks == 3)
  ) |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "blue"),
    locations = cells_body(
      rows = breaks == 4)
  )
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use data_color(), but specifiy target_columns to be everything(). This is from the gt() reference:

> When specifying a single column in columns we can use as many target_columns values as we want. Let's make another countrypops-based table where we map the generated colors from the year column to all columns in the table. This time, the palette used is "inferno" (also from the viridis package).

```
countrypops |>
  dplyr::filter(country_code_3 %in% c("FRA", "GBR", "ITA")) |>
  dplyr::select(-contains("code")) |>
  dplyr::filter(year %% 5 == 0) |>
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = "country_name",
    values_from = "population"
  ) |>
  gt() |>
  fmt_integer(columns = c(everything(), -year)) |>
  cols_width(
    year ~ px(80),
    everything() ~ px(160)
  ) |>
  opt_all_caps() |>
  opt_vertical_padding(scale = 0.75) |>
  opt_horizontal_padding(scale = 3) |>
  data_color(
    columns = year,
    target_columns = everything(),
    palette = "inferno"
  ) |>
  tab_options(
    table_body.hlines.style = "none",
    column_labels.border.top.color = "black",
    column_labels.border.bottom.color = "black",
    table_body.border.bottom.color = "black"
  )
```